# If $f(x)=8x^3+3x$ , $x\in\mathbb{R}$, how do I find $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^{1/3}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be defined as $f(x)=8x^3+3x$. Then $f$ is continuous , strictly increasing, and

$\lim _{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty , \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ , so $f$ is injective and surjective . How do I compute

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac {f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^{1/3}}?$$

Comment: $$x\to\infty\iff x^3\to \infty$$

Answer (score 8):

I got something different than the one in the prevous answer:

$f^{-1}(8x)=z$ and $f^{-1}(x)=y$ so

$8x=8z^{3}+3z$ and $x=8y^{3}+3y$

Therefore,

$8z^{3}\left ( 1+\frac{3}{z^{2}} \right )=8x\Rightarrow z\left ( 1+\frac{3}{z^{2}} \right )^{1/3}=x^{1/3}$ and similarly

$2y\left ( 1+\frac{3}{8y^{2}} \right )^{1/3}=x^{1/3}$.

Now, substituting, then factoring and cancelling $x^{1/3}$, we get

$\dfrac{z-y}{x^{1/3}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{x^{1/3}}{\left ( 1+\dfrac{3}{z^{2}} \right )^{1/3}}-\left (\dfrac{ x^{1/3}}{2\left ( 1+\dfrac{3}{8y^{2}} \right )^{1/3}}\right )}{x^{1/3}}=\\\dfrac{1}{\left ( 1+\dfrac{3}{z^{2}} \right )^{1/3}}-\left (\dfrac{1}{2\left ( 1+\dfrac{3}{8y^{2}} \right )^{1/3}}\right )$.

As $x\rightarrow \infty $, $z\rightarrow \infty$ so upon taking limits, we obtain $1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 4):

One has
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}{f^{-1}(8y)\over y^{1/3}}=2\lim_{y\to\infty}{f^{-1}(8y)\over(8y)^{1/3}}=2\lim_{z\to\infty}{f^{-1}(z)\over z^{1/3}}\ .$$
Therefore the quantity in $Q$ in question is equal to
$$Q=\lim_{z\to\infty}{f^{-1}(z)\over z^{1/3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{f^{-1}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\over \bigl(f(x)\bigr)^{1/3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{x\over 2x\bigl(1+{3\over 8x^2}\bigr)^{1/3}}={1\over2}\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

let $$f^{-1}(8x) = z, f^{-1}(x) = y.$$  then $$8x = f(z) = 8z^3+3z \to z = 2x^{1/3}+\cdots\tag 1$$ in the same way $$y = x^{1/3} + \cdots \tag 2$$  therefore $$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac {f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^{1/3}} =\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{z-y}{x^{1/3}} = 1.$$

Comment: I couldn't understand that $z=2x^{1/3}+...$ thing

Comment: @Saun Dev Note that when $x$ tends to $+ \infty$ $f(x)$ is equivalent to $8x^3$, so for these values of $x$ we can neglect $3x$....and invert the dominant term you get $z=...$

Comment: @abel there is a misprint, it should be $f(z)=\color{red}{8}z^3+3z$

Comment: @Idris, thanks for spotting the typo.

Comment: imagine solving it in a time bounded situation....

Answer (score 2):

Well. Both solutions of abel and Chilango are the same and both contains different misprint. I will give correction for both.

For Chilango.  The number $1$ inside the first parenthesis should be $8$
$$z^{3}\left ( \color{red}{1}+\frac{3}{z^{2}} \right )=8x\Rightarrow z\left ( 1+\frac{3}{z^{2}} \right )^{1/3}=2x^{1/3}$$
Correcting this one obtains the final limit equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

For abel. His misprint is the coefficient of $z^3$ it should be $8$ but not $1$ $$8x = f(z) = \color{red}{8}z^3+3z \to z = \color{red}{1}x^{1/3}+\cdots\tag 1$$ Taking into account this correction the limit is the same : $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach:

Asymptotically, we can write $f(x) \sim 8x^3 \implies f^{-1}(x)\sim\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)^{1/3}$. then
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^{1/3}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^{1/3}-(x/8)^{1/3}}{x^{1/3}} =\frac{1}{2}.$$