# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(2021x)-f^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt[2021] x}$, where $f(x)=2021x^{2021}+x+1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, inverse-function

> Let $f(x)=2021x^{2021}+x+1$, and compute the following limit:
> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(2021x)-f^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt[2021] x}$$

My attempt: i want to use mean value theorem to $f^{-1}(x)$ then we have:
$ \frac{2020x}{((2021)^2 (η_y)^{2021}+1)(\sqrt[2021] x)}$.
And $f(η_y)=η_x$, $η_x∈(x,2021x) $. We know $η_x$ tend to 0 as x tend to $\infty$ so from the expression of $f$ we know $η_y$ is also.but we  don't know  the quotient of $η_y$ and $x$, so i think this way is fail. But i can't do it in other way.

Comment: by $2021 x^2 021 $ maybe you mean $ 2021 x ^ {2021} $?

Comment: It is $ 2021 x ^ {2021} $

Comment: $\eta_x \rightarrow \infty $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and not $0$. Then you can just observe that it is like a rational function $\frac{x}{ \eta_x^{2021} x^{\frac{1}{2021}}} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Does the limit exist?

Comment: where is this problem form actually?

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore, it is  a Calculus exam problem

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3063992/72031

Comment: The effort to solve the problem is greatly reduced once you replace $2021$ by some symbol, say $k$.

Comment: Another duplicate found with approach0: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1326952/72031

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=x^{1/2021}$, then $x\to\infty$ iff $y\to\infty$, so we consider the limit
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(2021y^{2021})-f^{-1}(y^{2021})}{y}.$$
Note that $f$ is strictly increasing, so $f^{-1}(2021y^{2021})<y$. Note that $2021y^{2021}-f(y-1)$ is a polynomial of even degree $2020$ whose leading term has a positive coefficient $2021^2>0$, so when $|y|$ is sufficiently large, we have $f(y-1)<2021y^{2021}$ and thus $y-1<f^{-1}(2021y^{2021})$. Hence
$$0<\left|\frac{f^{-1}(2021y^{2021})-y}{y}\right|<\frac1{|y|}, \qquad |y|>>1.$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(2021y^{2021})}{y}=1.$$
And so
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(y^{2021})}{y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(2021(2021^{-1/2021}y^{2021}))}{y}=2021^{-1/2021}.$$
Finally,
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(2021y^{2021})-f^{-1}(y^{2021})}{y}=1-2021^{-1/2021}=1-\left(\frac1{2021}\right)^{1/2021}.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$L=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(2021x)}{\sqrt[2021]x}=\sqrt[2021]{2021}\lim_{u\to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}u}{\sqrt[2021]{u}}$$ now let $u=f(x)$ $$L=\sqrt[2021]{2021}\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt[2021]{2021x^{2021}+x+1}}=1$$ now $$\tau=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{-1}x}{\sqrt[2021]{x}}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{f^{-1}(f(t))}{\sqrt[2021]{f(t)}}=\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{t}{\sqrt[2021]{2021t^{2021}+t+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[2021]{2021}}$$ therefore required value is $$L-\tau=?$$

Comment: Just wanted to check why you disagreed with the closure of question as a duplicate. Please let me know your views on this.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I disagreed because atleast in first sight the method used in duplicate target did not seem to be to be *obviously* applicable to this question 2) I think the answers to to the duplicate target where rather complicated and with my limited knowledge i couldnt understand their solutions either .The solutions posted  by other users on this question seemed more nicer(for me)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Nevertheless if you feel my reasons are not quite satisfactory /you feel I am violating some code of conduct  I am willing to close this as a duplicate

Comment: I understand your point. I have no intention to close as duplicate just for the sake of closing. And you will be surprised that there is another duplicate whose [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327642/72031) uses same technique as yours. You have not violated any code of conduct and I have seen some of your other contributions and I value them!

Comment: It's just that there is lot of material on mathse which lies unorganized. Close as dupe is just one way to sort this mess. Forgot to do a +1

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ we have
$$
2021x^{2021}<f(x)<(2021+\epsilon)x^{2021}
$$
which holds for sufficiently large $x$. Hence
$$
(\frac{x}{2021+\epsilon})^\frac{1}{2021}<f^{-1}(x)<(\frac{x}{2021})^\frac{1}{2021},
$$
from which
$$
(\frac{x}{1+\epsilon_1})^\frac{1}{2021}<f^{-1}(2021x)<(x)^\frac{1}{2021},
$$
where $\epsilon_1=\epsilon/2021$ and we can write
$$
(\frac{2021}{2021+\epsilon})^\frac{1}{2021}-(\frac{1}{2021})^\frac{1}{2021}
<
\frac{f^{-1}(2021x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^{\frac{1}{2021}}}<1-(\frac{1}{2021+\epsilon})^\frac{1}{2021}.
$$
Since the above bounds hold for any $\epsilon>0$, the limit must be
$
1-(\frac{1}{2021})^\frac{1}{2021}\approx 0.00375904653
$
.