# If $f:R\to R, f(x)=8x^3+3x$, then find $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

This relates to a previous MSE question involving an asymptotic limit:

[If $f(x)=8x^3+3x$ , $x\in\mathbb{R}$, how do I find $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x^{1/3}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326952/if-fx-8x33x-x-in-mathbbr-how-do-i-find-lim-x-to-infty-frac-f/4618270#4618270)

Here, we seek the near-zero limit of the same expression.

So the new question is  $f:R\to R, f(x)=8x^3+3x$, then find $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x}.$$
Near zero $3x$ term ,so we take $f(x)\sim 3x \implies f^{-1}(x)\sim\frac{x}{3}.
$
Hence, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{8x/3-x/3}{x}=\frac{7}{3}.$$

The question here is question is whether the problem and solution are correct and what could be alternate ways of solving it?

**EDIT:**
More rigorously as per the suggestion of @Paramanand Singh, notet that if $y=f(x)$ and inverse exists then
$$\frac{d f^{-1}(y)}{dy}|_{y=y_0}=\frac{1}{f(x_0)}, y_0=f(x_0)$$
This limit can be seen as due to L-Hospital, wherein we can use
$(f^{-1})'(8x)=\frac{8}{24x^2+3}=\frac{1}{3}$, when ${x \to 0}$

Comment: Your limit is essentially a derivative $g'(0)$ where $g(x) =f^{-1}(8x)-f^{-1}(x)$. Use the rules of derivatives combined with $f'(0)=3$

Comment: Your own approach needs to be made rigorous by writing $f'(0)=3\implies (f^{-1})'(0)=1/3$ so that $f^{-1}(x)=(x/3)+o(x)$ and then the limit is $7/3$.